# Mi formulario de contacto me devuelve errores al enviar mensajes

Tags: php, formularios

Tengo un inconveniente con mi página, estoy seguro que es algo muy simple pero no me estoy dando cuenta donde tengo el error. El problema consiste en que no me funciona el formulario de contacto, me tira el siguiente error:

"Lo sentimos, hubo un error en sus datos y el formulario no puede ser enviado en este momento. Detalle de los errores.
Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.
Porfavor corrija estos errores e inténtelo de nuevo."
Y no encuentro la forma de entender dónde esta el error.

El link de mi página es http://indgraphicdesign.com.ar/contacto.html

Y acá les adjunto mi código PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

     $email_to = "
 ind.graphicdesign@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Mail de la página";   

    function died($error) {

        // si hay algún error, el formulario puede desplegar su mensaje de aviso

        echo "Lo sentimos, hubo un error en sus datos y el formulario no puede ser enviado en este momento. ";

        echo "Detalle de los errores.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Porfavor corrija estos errores e inténtelo de nuevo.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // Se valida que los campos del formulairo estén llenos

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['message'])) {

        died('Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.');       

    }
 //En esta parte el valor "name" nos sirve para crear las variables que recolectaran la información de cada campo

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // requerido

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // requerido

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // requerido

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // no requerido 

    $message = $_POST['message']; // requerido

    $error = ""; //Linea numero 52

//En esta parte se verifica que la dirección de correo sea válida 

   $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'La dirección de correo proporcionada no es válida.<br />';

  }

//En esta parte se validan las cadenas de texto

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'El formato del nombre no es válido<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'el formato del apellido no es válido.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($message) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'El formato del texto no es válido.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

//A partir de aqui se contruye el cuerpo del mensaje tal y como llegará al correo

    $email_message = "Contenido del Mensaje.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "Nombre: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Apellido: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Teléfono: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Mensaje: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


//Se crean los encabezados del correo

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- incluye aqui tu propio mensaje de Éxito-->

Gracias! Nos pondremos en contacto contigo a la brevedad


<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: a $error = "" le falta un punto y coma es decir debe quedar $error = "";

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque se trata de un simple error tipográfico.

Comment: Gracias, no me habia percatado, ahi lo modifique y ahora el error es el siguiente:
"Lo sentimos, hubo un error en sus datos y el formulario no puede ser enviado en este momento. Detalle de los errores.

Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.

Porfavor corrija estos errores e inténtelo de nuevo."

Comment: @NicolasDure ese segundo "error" que mencionas en tu comentario corresponde a otra pregunta, te recomendaría primero revisar un poco qué sucede en la aplicación, quizás un debug o escribir mensajes para evaluar cómo se comporta la aplicación

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error : "Lo sentimos, hubo un error en sus datos y el formulario no puede ser enviado en este momento. Detalle de los errores.Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.Porfavor corrija estos errores e inténtelo de nuevo." No me da mas detalle que eso, y los mails no se envian directamente. Entiendo muy poco de php, agradeceria cualquier ayuda o sugerencia

Comment: No se debe cambiar la pregunta así. Deberías haber creado una nueva con el nuevo problema en lugar de modificar completamente ésta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$error = "" //Linea numero 52`
Te falta un punto y coma al final..

Deberia quedar asi
`$error = ""; //Linea numero 52`

**Updateaste la pregunta asi que update mi respuesta aca abajo...**

Primero que nada el form:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="send_form_email.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                    <label>Nombre <span class="ind">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Tu nombre" required>
                        <label>Apellido</label>
                        <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Tu apellido" required>
                        <label>Email <span class="ind">*</span></label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ejemplo@correo.com" required>
                        <label>Telefono <span class="ind">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="11-5045-0256" name="telefono">
                        <label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
                        <textarea id= "mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder= "Escribe tu consulta aquí, responderémos en breve." required=""></textarea>
                        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
                        <input type="file" size=60 name="file1"><br><br>
                        <input id= "submit" type= "submit" name= "submit" <a href="http://www.indgraphicdesign.com.ar/email_form.php" value= "Enviar" />
                        <br><br>
</form>
```

**Fijate que tenes un form dentro de un form..** =)

Segundo, en el form, los nombres de los inputs no coinciden con lo que espera el post..

Ejemplo :

```
<input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Tu apellido" required>
```

Esto estaria enviando lo siguiente:

```
$_POST['apellido'];
```

Tenes que igualar las variables a las que tenes en esta condición:

```
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['message'])) {

        died('Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.');       

    }
```

La función isset de PHP se fija si existe y esta definida esa variable, en este caso por ejemplo

```
isset($_POST['first_name'])
```

Lo que esta haciendo es validar si existe y esta definido el `$_POST['first_name']`, si la variable no esta definida retorna FALSE por ende el if te manda a la funcion "dead".

Un tip por si no te das cuenta es hacer lo siguiente..
En tu file PHP al que envia el form arriba de todo hacele un **print** al $_POST para ver que esta retornando y agregale un exist para que solamente muestre eso :P

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Saludos,

Comment: No me deja hacer otra respuesta o no veo donde ( Estoy ciego jaja ).
Hay una variable en el post que no te esta llegando y por eso se llama a la función "died" que te muestra ese error! .

Comment: Genial, simplemente genial @Fakux , corregi los valores q no coincidian y el mail me llego, lo unico que no se envian son las imagenes que uno carga, pero calculo que eso ya esta relacionado con las bases de datos no? Gracias por la ayuda desde ya

Comment: ahh claro.. eso porque nunca se define la varible $error_message y como no la encuentra no puede validar el strlen..
No se porque lo hicieron así pero podrias solucionarlo haciendo lo siguiente:

if(isset($error_message)){

}

Comment: Y eso como lo aplicaría? yo borre la linea 100 y ahora el mail me llega bien y dice el mensaje de enviado correctamente en una pestaña nueva, @Fakux, tenes idea como puedo hacer para solucionar lo del envio de archivos? porque los carga aparentemente pero nunca llegan a mi mail y eso seria bastante impresindible para que mis clientes me envien sus archivos. Solucionando eso ya quedaría terminado

Comment: La verdad no veo en el pregunta como tenes el formulario actualmente, no veo donde se esta guardando la imagen o como la incluis en tu mail(newsletter). En base a esta argumentación no te puedo responder eso..

Comment: Perdón, esta subida actualmente al link que deje antes, ahi lo vuelvo a dejar [http://indgraphicdesign.com.ar/contacto.html]

Nose, probé buscar un archivo para subir y aparentemente lo marca como para enviar, puede que no lo este incluyendo realmente. La parte que corregí gracias a vos quedó así:

`$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // requerido
 $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // requerido
 $email_from = $_POST['email']; // requerido
 $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // no requerido 
 $message = $_POST['message']; // requerido
 $error = ""; //Linea numero 52`

Comment: @NicolasDure, La realidad es que es complicado de explicar justamente aca en un comentario, creo que este post esta solcuionado, te recomiendo que realizes una nueva pregunta, y consulta detalladamente que queres hacer, se puede enbeber la imagen en correo tipo un newsletter o adjuntarla, además adjunta el correspondiente codigo ya que en el que envias no veo que en ningun momento trabajes con el array $_FILES que es el que posee las imagenes que llegan de tu formulario =)

Comment: Dale Fakux, te agradezco mucho, armare una pregunta nueva por ese otro tema, pero este quedo solucionado con tu respuesta. Gracias y buen dia